# Validation of Select Attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, panel

I have a small 4 step wizard that will guide a user through a registration process. I have javascript that will make sure that the required fields are valid and to go between the pages in the wizard. I have been unable to get my select dropdown required. I've tried to use the required tag but it doesn't work. Am I forgetting something in my javascript? I want the user to be required to select a State from the dropdown. I also have a few other dropdowns that don't work either. I'm using panel from Bootstrap 3 to house my content. Also the validation is only working on the first page so I'm guessing that I have some problems with my javascript

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
      allWells = $('.setup-content'),
      allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
        navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
        $item.addClass('btn-success');
        allWells.hide();
        $target.show();
        $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function () {
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'], input[type='select']"),
        isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
          isValid = false;
          $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
      }

      if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-success').trigger('click');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="stepwizard">
            <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">1</a>
                    <p><small>Personal Information</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                    <p><small>Security</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                    <p><small>Church Affiliation</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
                    <p><small>Payment</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <form action="/login/Create" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Personal Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Address 2</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" id="address2" placeholder="Address 2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">City</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">State</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" required>
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="CA">California</option>
                                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="IL">Ilinois</option>
                                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Island</option>
                                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="OK">Oaklahoma</option>
                                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="SD">Soth Dakota</option>
                                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
                                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Zip</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Cell Phone</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="tel" required="required" class="form-control" name="cell" id="cell" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Account Security</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="cnfPassword" id="cnfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Security Question</label>
                            <select name="secQuestion"required class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var secretquestion in Model.securityquestions)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@secretquestion.id">@secretquestion.Question</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Security Answer</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="secAnswer" id="secAnswer" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Account PIN</label>
                            <input maxlength="6" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="pin" id="pin" placeholder="PIN" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Church Affiliation</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 1</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil1" id="chAffil1">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 2</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil2" id="chAffil2">
                                <option value"">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 3</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil3" id="chAffil3">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 4</label><br />
                            <select class="select2 form-control" style="width:100%" name="chAffil4" id="chAffil4">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-4">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Payment</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cardName">Name on Card</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cardName" class="form-control" id="cardName" placeholder="Name on Card">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-number">
                            Credit or debit card
                        </label>
                        <div id="card-number">
                            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="card-vc">
                                    CVC
                                </label>
                                <div id="card-cvc">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="card-expiration">
                                    Exp
                                </label>
                                <div id="card-expiration">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The State dropdown (`<select>`) and password and telephone fields (`<input type="password">` and `<input type="tel">`) are not validated, because those elements are not found with this selector that you are using:

```js
var curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'], input[type='select']");
```

You should instead use e.g. this to get all input fields and all dropdowns (`<select>` elements):

```js
var curInputs = curStep.find("input, select");
```

This seems to fix the problems you have, though make sure that all inputs that need validation have the `required` attribute.

---

Here's your code with the above fix so you can try it:

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
      allWells = $('.setup-content'),
      allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
        navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
        $item.addClass('btn-success');
        allWells.hide();
        $target.show();
        $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function () {
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input, select"),
        isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
          isValid = false;
          $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
      }

      if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-success').trigger('click');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="stepwizard">
            <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">1</a>
                    <p><small>Personal Information</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                    <p><small>Security</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                    <p><small>Church Affiliation</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="stepwizard-step col-xs-3">
                    <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
                    <p><small>Payment</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <form action="/login/Create" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Personal Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Address 2</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" id="address2" placeholder="Address 2" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">City</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">State</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" required>
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="CA">California</option>
                                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="IL">Ilinois</option>
                                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Island</option>
                                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="OK">Oaklahoma</option>
                                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="SD">Soth Dakota</option>
                                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
                                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Zip</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Cell Phone</label>
                            <input maxlength="100" type="tel" required="required" class="form-control" name="cell" id="cell" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Account Security</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="cnfPassword" id="cnfPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Security Question</label>
                            <select name="secQuestion"required class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var secretquestion in Model.securityquestions)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@secretquestion.id">@secretquestion.Question</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Security Answer</label>
                            <input maxlength="200" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="secAnswer" id="secAnswer" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label">Account PIN</label>
                            <input maxlength="6" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" name="pin" id="pin" placeholder="PIN" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Church Affiliation</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 1</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil1" id="chAffil1">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 2</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil2" id="chAffil2">
                                <option value"">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 3</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control select2" style="width:100%" name="chAffil3" id="chAffil3">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Church Affiliation 4</label><br />
                            <select class="select2 form-control" style="width:100%" name="chAffil4" id="chAffil4">
                                <option value="">None</option>
                                @{
                                    foreach (var churches in Model.churches)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@churches.id">@churches.ChurchName @churches.ChuchDenomination @churches.ChurchType - @churches.ChurchCity, @churches.ChurchState </option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-4">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Payment</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cardName">Name on Card</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cardName" class="form-control" id="cardName" placeholder="Name on Card">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-number">
                            Credit or debit card
                        </label>
                        <div id="card-number">
                            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="card-vc">
                                    CVC
                                </label>
                                <div id="card-cvc">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="card-expiration">
                                    Exp
                                </label>
                                <div id="card-expiration">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```